# SQL subquery causing overall query to go slow

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-tuning

The below query takes several minutes(never completes sometimes) to execute. I'm using `MySQL` database.

```
select 
        customer_name as cust,
        SUM(num_visits) AS visits
     from 
        visit_history
     where
            category = "middleMan"
            and eve_date >= '2014-07-01' and eve_date <= '2015-07-01
            and eve_type='XCG'
            and eve_master IN (select eve_name from master_type_ahj where category = "middleMan"  and eve_date >= '2014-07-01' and eve_date <= '2015-07-01')
     group by
        cust
    order by
        visits  desc 
    limit   
        50
```

The database table contains over million records. The data is partitioned. If I were to remove the subquery - `and eve_master IN (select eve_name from master_type_ahj where category = "middleMan"  and eve_date >= '2014-07-01' and eve_date <= '2015-07-01')`, the query completes in a few min.

The columns that go into `WHERE` clause are indexed.

Is there anyway I could tune this? Any help here would help me tune a bunch of related queries too. Could I ask for help here please?

Comment: Index the columns you search by, and consider using BETWEEN() for date comparisions, and/or unix timestamp conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way using a derived table

```
select 
    customer_name as cust,
    sum(num_visits) as visits
from visit_history
join (
    select distinct eve_name from master_type_ahj 
    where category = "middleMan"  
    and eve_date >= '2014-07-01' 
    and eve_date <= '2015-07-01'
) t on t.eve_name = visit_history.eve_master
where category = "middleMan"
    and eve_date >= '2014-07-01' and eve_date <= '2015-07-01'
    and eve_type='XCG'
group by cust
order by visits desc 
limit 50
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Where the query never returned in about 30 min or more & still didn't complete , now 2 years worth of data comes back in about 4 sec :) I honestly can't thank you enough.

Comment: @usert4jju7 glad it helped

Comment: Also with respect to one of the comments above, is using `BETWEEN` efficient(faster) than using greater than & less than criteria? Would you be able to please clarify?

Comment: @usert4jju7 I don't believe using between is faster than using inequality operators. But the best way to check is to test it yourself

Comment: Sure. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL often handles `EXISTS` better than `IN`.  So, this is your query:

```
select customer_name as cust, SUM(num_visits) AS visits
from visit_history
where category = 'middleMan' and
      eve_date >= '2014-07-01' and eve_date <= '2015-07-01 and
      eve_type = 'XCG' and
      exists (select 1
              from master_type_ahj m2
              where m2.eve_master = vh.eve_master
                    m2.category = 'middleMan'  and
                    m2.eve_date >= '2014-07-01' and eve_date <= '2015-07-01'
             )
group by cust
order by visits  desc 
limit 50;
```

I would recommend indexes on `visit_history(category, eve_type, eve_date, eve_master)`. and `master_type_ahj(eve_master, category, eve_date)`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I guess you meant to say "MySQL often handles EXISTS better than IN.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon. The query was way faster than that in my question. The derived tables concept posted below works super fast & hence, I accepted the answer. Thank you again for offering help

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an actual `join` would be more efficient:

```
select 
      vh.customer_name as cust,
      SUM(vh.num_visits) AS visits
    from 
      visit_history as vh
      inner join 
      master_type_ahj as mt on vh.eve_master = mt.eve_name
    where
      vh.category = "middleMan"
      and vh.eve_date >= '2014-07-01' and vh.eve_date <= '2015-07-01
      and vh.eve_type='XCG'
      and mt.category = "middleMan"  
      and mt.eve_date >= '2014-07-01' and mt.eve_date <= '2015-07-01'
```

You may also learn more by using `explain` to see what mysql is actually doing to handle your query.

Comment: Thank you . This one is still slow. The above answer using derived tables worked like a charm